# Overloading friend operator method in template class

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, friend-function

I'm trying to overload the assignment ('=') operator of a template class, but I need the `operator=` method to be a friend function.

I though this would be simple, but I'm doing something wrong because the code below causes a compilation error:

> error C2801: 'operator =' must be a non-static member

```
template <typename T>
class IDataStream
{
public:
    friend void operator=(const IDataStream& dataStream)
    {
        // set some private members, e.g.
        // this->{...} = dataStream.{...};
    };
}
```

Can someone show me the error of my ways- I've become pretty stuck on this :(
Thanks.

Comment: Why does it have to be a `friend`?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Because in operator=, I need to access private members of IDataStream.

Comment: Then what's wrong with it just being a regular member function? Member functions can access private data because they belong to the class itself. Besides, you can't make the assignment operator a non-member function (which you are doing by "befriending" it).

Comment: `operator=` cannot be a non-member. And it always needs two arguments, the implicit `this` and right-hand-side.

Comment: But member functions have access to private members

Comment: @0x499602D2 It turns out that tiredness makes me completely incompetent. I'd convinced myself (somehow) that it needed to be a friend, and thought that my error was in the combination of friend and operator overload...which it is also, but that issue should never have arisen in this case. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Your error is using `friend`, which changes the function from a member-function to an `inline`-defined `friend`-function.

`operator=` can only be defined as a non-static member-function, and needs two arguments, the implicit `this` and the explicit right-hand-side.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at the C++ standard.

> § 9.3/1 Functions declared in the definition of a class, **excluding
>   those declared with a friend specifier** (11.3), are called member
>   functions of that class. A member function may be declared static in
>   which case it is a static member function of its class (9.4);
>   otherwise it is a non-static member function of its class (9.3.1,
>   9.3.2).
>
> § 13.5.3/1 An assignment operator shall be implemented by a non-static
>   member function with exactly one parameter. *[..]*

So you cannot make `operator=` a friend.

In § 11 [class.access]:

> 1 A member of a class can be
>
> > — private; that is, its name can be used only by members and friends
> >     of the class in which it is declared.

Since a member function is a *member* of the class, it doesn't require the friend specifier to access private data members.

If you want to learn the proper way to overload an operator, please see [c++-faq](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq)'s [Operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4421706/3920237), although the meat of overloading `operator=` is covered in [What is the copy-and-swap idiom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom).

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by 0x499602D2, `operator=` doesn't need to be a friend function. I'm blaming tiredness for managing to completely overlook that objects have access to private & protected members of objects of the same class...